# Garage wiring puzzle

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, junction-box

I'm trying to figure out the wiring in my finished garage. It has two ceiling junction boxes, with attached porcelain lights, and three wall outlets.

I'll say up front that all of this was done safely...

I opened up what I think is the "main" ceiling junction box and found four armored cables junctioned here. Okay, I think I guessed right. Three of the cables have just a white wire and a black wire, and one of the cables has a white, a black, and a red traveler.

I separated the four ganged black wires and figured out which is the "power in" with a non-contact voltage tester. We'll call this Hot #1.

I connect each of the other Hots, in turn, to Hot #1 and got these results:

- Hot #1 to Hot #2 powers the other ceiling light fixture. Btw, this Cable #2 is the one with the red traveler.
- Hot #1 to Hot #3 powers Outlet A and Outlet B.
- Hot #1 to Hot #4 powers Outlet C, and surprisingly, also Outlet A.

Huh?! That last one doesn't make sense to me. Can anyone clue me in to what's going on?

Comment: Need to know what switches you have and what positions/connections they have on them (you haven't necessarily given us all the info). Why did you decide the red is a traveller and not another hot or a switched circuit beyond the "other light".

Comment: There is a single switch, which controls both lights and which I assume is attached to Light/Junction #2, and which I also assume is what the red wire is for.  This is why I assume the red is a traveler.

Comment: I mean, I assume the red is a traveler, because the cable that contains the red wire is Hot #2 that controls the other light and just past that, on the wall, is where the switch is (standard on/off).

Comment: I just opened up Light/Junction #2.  I was right, it has only two cables: a white/black/red from Junction #1, and a white/black/red going to the wall switch.

Comment: What is the question ? did you have problem before you started, if so what was it ?  Did you take notes and how things were wired in the "main" box ? Are trying to get it back to the way it was, did you take apart the wires to try and fix a problem ? How do you want it function ?  You can not assume with wiring, you need to know were each wire goes and why.

Comment: You've identified the red continues on. What does it go to (wired to), and what is it doing in the switch box? You only have one switch for all of this circuit, are any of the outlets setup to be switched?

Comment: The question is: Please explain how this could be wired to allow the above testing results.  House was built 60+ years ago and I want to understand how this is wired before I make changes.

Comment: @nobyman: None of the outlets are switched.  The one switch controls only the two lights, not "all of this".

Comment: You haven't described how the two light fixtures were wired at each junction box. Were they connected to the red wire(s)?

Comment: Are you only testing with the voltage tester, or are you also plugging in a practical load like a vacuum cleaner? Sometimes testers will read up phantom voltage...

Comment: I have also tested with a plugged-in device (drill).

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please (lights, receptacles, switch)?

Comment: What you suggest isn't what's happening unless your guess(es) or information provided is wrong, or your test made unintended connections. (numerous things beyond what you've described can be going on e.g., An outlet can be split top/bottom. There should be a black(or a white, or both) in one of your lights that controls the switching of the lights (but you havent described one)). And still, what is the red doing at all ends?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the answer.

It turns out there must be another junction box.  I made an incorrect assumption that Light/Junction #1 is the main junction.  It isn't.

It appears to be wired like this: Breaker feeds some junction that I can't see which then feeds Outlet A and Light/Junction #1.

So anytime the breaker is on, Outlet A is powered no matter what.

Really sucks if this main junction is in the finished garage ceiling and no way to find it without busting up that ceiling (cement/plaster type with lath of heavy wire mesh).  Jeez, all they had to do was put the main junction in the unfinished ceiling of the adjacent laundry room where the power cable comes through anyway.

Update: There may not be another junction box afterall.  See photos.  That's a very tiny access hole that I pushed my phone up against.  You can't see the full width of the joist bay.  Two cables coming back towards the camera.  One is the cable from the breaker and the other actually goes down the wall to Outlet A.  The two cables going horizontally to the left is odd, since the only thing over there is Outlet B.  More investigation is needed, but it looks like I might be able to feed a new 20 amp (12 gauge) cable through here, which is what I've been wanting to do.  Unfortunately, there's no access on the other side for Outlet C and this junction box can't be removed without busting up the ceiling as the cross bar mounting goes *through* the box.

Update 2: There is indeed another junction box, but it is not hidden.  Well, sort of.  The furnace duct in the garage is very close to the wall where Outlet A is.  The photos I took put the junction much closer to the wall than the known Light/Junction #1.  Sure enough, there is another Light/Junction "hidden" behind the duct.  No bulb in it, so I never knew it was there.  But this is definitely the main box for the garage.  Whew!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Glad you were able to get it sorted! Hidden junction boxes sure are a pain in the rump...

Comment: Did you alreadyconfirm that outlet A isnt whats feeding the light? It seems you are asserting that there is a hidden junction, but if what you are describing in this answer is accurate, theres still not enough information to make this claim unless you have now opened the outlet and confirmed there is only 1 romex/shielded wire coming into it.

Comment: @noybman: All of the outlets have only 1 cable (armored) coming into them.  My answer is based on a test that I must have missed before...When all hots are disconnected in Light/Junction #1 the only thing powered is Outlet A (which has only one cable in it).

Comment: Thank you for confirming regarding that there is only one cable in each outlet. The last location you have not ruled out to us with the given information is the swtich box itself. The breaker fed cable can be in it, and spltting to lights and outlets. Also, just for completeness, please tell us what the red wire is doing between the lights (presumalby it is a no connection based on what you haven't told us).

Comment: Well, the switch is at the other end of the garage, over 15 feet away.  The only cable entering the garage is exactly where the Outlet A is.  So there must be a junction very close by.  Too bad the ceiling is constructed like it is.  The ceiling junction boxes can't even be pulled out without tearing into the ceiling.  If I was a masochist I would be tempted to pull the wood flooring in the room above to get full access.  Way too much work.

Comment: So the red wire is a no connect? You should avoid guesswork with AC. The reason why I've been persisting is because there should not be hidden boxes (by code), and since you own this home it would behoove you to know its secrets (in case its ever a trouble spot). You can buy a toner at a big box store and disconnect your two endpoints (do so safely; the breaker side & the 4 way light location you found); hookup toner at breaker wire side) and you'll most likely be able to "smell" the wire - it "should" beep much louder when you find its box, or at least the path it goes to.

Comment: Red wire isn't a concern of mine, because it is used for the other light and the wall switch.  Power only comes into the garage at the other end, where Outlet A is.  Power goes into the garage ceiling to a junction box that I can't access.  It then splits and goes to Outlet A and the aforementioned Light/Junction #1 with the four cables coming in.  It certainly explains my test results.  And, yes, I want to know my house's secrets.  It was built 60+ years ago, though, and I suspect the code was not as strict as today.

Comment: A sniffer/toner may not work here as 1) all the cables are armored and 2) the ceiling in the garage has a metal mesh lathe as the base for the cement-like plaster...I would expect both of those would shield too much.

Comment: I've been following your thread for the last few weeks hoping you'd get it sorted out. Guesswork is dangerous especially with voltages that can kill or burn, the peace of mind you now have pays for itself. You're right, sniffers through "metal" can lead you astray but it sometimes can get you in the right direction. You could ask an electrician to runa new cable since they often have a full toolbox of tricks to fish cable, but I'd expect some drywall rework will be needed. Congrats! +1

Comment: If it was drywall I'd already be tearing into it.  But the garage ceiling is a cement-type of plaster with I think sand in it and it has a heavy wire mesh as the lath.  Drywall repairs are simple.  What I have isn't an easy repair.  I'm starting to tear into it today, because it looks like I can run new 12 gauge cable by just cutting out the oil ceiling boxes and replacing them with new ones that have a box that unfastens from the crossbar.  Doesn't appear to be a need to cut into the ceiling at all.  Discovering that main junction box has been the key.

Comment: ^ "old", not "oil".

Comment: Semi-related - there exist "bore scope cameras" for under $10 that plug into a phone for power and display.  They're excellent for poking into all sorts of weird places and can help see things with a 10mm hole and a wire, that you would normally need a much larger hole to see through.

Answer (score 0):

It *could* be that Cable #2 (the 3-conductor cable) from Main light to Other light carries neutral and hot to Other light and to Wall switch. The red wire then brings switched hot back to Other and to Main lights.

The only other mystery is the result that Cable #3 and Cable #4 both powered Outlet A. Supposing Outlet A is a duplex receptacle, are both of its sockets powered in both conditions -- or one socket with Cable #3 and the other socket with Cable #4?

It's also possible that you have something more advanced going on, such as a multi-wire branch circuit. You'd have to bring us photos, and/or measure with a volt meter the voltage between hot-hot and hot-neutral pairings of wires for us to assess that possibility.